# How to complete a process before moving to the next process in expect?

Tags: expect

I want to write a short code which executes a program with a different value every time - and this as much as often I want to. The program is a .cxx-macro which I call via ROOT in shell/ubuntu terminal.

The actual code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
exp_internal 0

spawn root -l

send ".L AnaProto_mainz.cxx+\r"
send "AnaProto_mainz(\"rough_cooled_3.root\", \"Complete_Matrix_0.0.root\",25,0,0.0)\r"
expect eof
send "AnaProto_mainz(\"rough_cooled_3.root\", \"Complete_Matrix_0.5.root\",25,0,0.5)\r"
expect eof
send "AnaProto_mainz(\"rough_cooled_3.root\", \"Complete_Matrix_1.0.root\",25,0,1.0)\r" 
(...)

interact
```

The problem is that `expect` calls every line directly without waiting the previous to complete or finish the task. I then realised that this is ok somehow because all the processes are executed parallely but by 3-5 parallel process ROOT crashes because the RAM is overloaded.

So I need the script to end one process before it executes the next process.
How can I do this ? Eof does not work, obviously and catch wait result does it neither. Or am I applying it wrongly? What is the command I'm looking for?

Comment: I got it somehow working:

`expect {
 timeout 
  {
   puts "\r"
          puts " ~ Shell: Waiting to complete current process "Complete_Matrix_$x".. ~"
   puts "\r"
          exp_continue
  }
      "...dary! Legendary!" 
}
interact`

But I get now the following problem: *** Error in `/usr/bin/root.exe': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000767bc00 ***

Again I have no free memory.

Comment: Fixed that, too. I now close expect before it proceeds the next root process. Probably it does not matter if you close expect or root. It's now working so I don't mind which of both is better :)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (not a comment), and accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle multiple Spawn process in expect script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820661/handle-multiple-spawn-process-in-expect-script)